# Spring roo App runs fine in STS but I get an Error when I run the same app in Cloud foundry

Tags: spring, cloud, cloud-foundry

I desperately need help on this.
I have an application and that deploys and runs fine in STS.

The application also deploys and starts up fine on cloud foundry.
However, when I try to access the a service in the user controller, I get the error given below.....
Any pointers will be highly appreciated...

2012-02-04 19:58:54,267 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfi gurerSupport - BeanFactory has not been set on BeanConfigurerSupport: Make sure this configurer runs in a Spring container. Unable to configure bean of type [com.xxxx.domain.CUser]. Proceeding without injection.
2012-02-04 19:58:54,942 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager - Get connection for route HttpRoute[{}->http://xxxx.cloudfoundry.com:80]
2012-02-04 19:59:00,636 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
2012-02-04 19:59:00,650 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
2012-02-04 19:59:00,651 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /xxxx/cuser/create HTTP/1.1
2012-02-04 19:59:00,651 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "POST /xxxx/cuser/create HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
2012-02-04 19:59:00,652 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Accept: */*[EOL]"
2012-02-04 19:59:00,652 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Content-Length: 133[EOL]"
2012-02-04 19:59:00,652 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Content-Type: application/json[EOL]"
2012-02-04 19:59:00,652 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - >> "Host: xxxx.cloudfoundry.com:80[EOL]"

Answer (score 1):

Please review the following links regarding roo + cloud foundry :

http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=base-cloud-foundry 
http://blog.springsource.com/2011/04/12/roo-cloud-foundry-productivity-in-the-cloud/

Is there any way you can share your source code or war file with us?

Also for more detail support it would be nice to post these type of questions on support.cloudfoundry.com